# MongoError: js:237:13 connect failed [localhost:27017]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular

I would like to install Mongodb on IntelliJ (already with Angular and Node.js). I installed MongoDB and changed my environment variables. I use Windows 10. When I try the command line : "mongo dbs show", I get this error :

> MongoDB shell version v3.4.10 connecting to:
>   mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/dbs 2017-11-20T16:59:43.003+0100 W NETWORK 
>   [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017 after 5000ms
>   milliseconds, giving up. 2017-11-20T16:59:43.003+0100 E QUERY
>   [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017,
>   connection attempt failed : connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
>   @(connect):1:6 exception: connect failed

In order to fix it, I tried the instructions of related posts, that is to say :
-Create a data directory in "MongoDB\Server\3.4\data"
-Change the directoy "mongod --dbpath=..."
-Change the allowed port to 27017 thank to "add --port 27017"

I did those operations but it doesn't solve the problem. Would you know how to fix it ? I thank you very much in advance !

Comment: Are you able to do `ps ax | grep mongo`?

Comment: For windows, you need to start mongod.exe and open mongo.exe in another terminal without closing the first terminal. For more info, follow https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.8/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

Comment: @Noah : I tried it but nothing appears on my screen. But not even an error message. I don't know if it's normal but when I try "ps ax", I don't see mongo's process running. What sould I do in your opinion ?

Comment: @Olscream Then mongo probably isn't running. Check the documentation of your install method to learn how to run it.